# Hide items in list based on group membership

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, formatting

I have a list of items in Sharepoint. I want to allow group members to submit items to the list, but I only want owners to be able to view the items.

[Microsoft has an example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/view-formatting#build-custom-row-layouts) of hiding fields in rows based on the row data:

```
"style": {
  "display": {
    "operator": "?",
    "operands": [
      {
        "operator": "==",
        "operands": [
          "@me",
          "[$Assigned_x0020_To.email]"
        ]
      },
      "",
      "none"
    ]
  }
}
```

But I want to a) hide entire rows and b) base it on group membership instead, and I can't find anything in their [sample catalog](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/tree/master/view-samples) that applies.

Answer (score 0):

It might be best to have a workflow that runs on item creation that sets item level permissions on the new item so that only the owners group has permissions to the item.